# DataTables add html after formated data

Tags: datatables

I'm rendering this data in my DataTable:

```
{"data":"price",
 render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 0, '$' )           
}
```

It returns a number like that "$9.999", so, i want a button after this (edit button), but i don't know how to do that. Something [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNsQp.png)

I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks, and i'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
render: function(data,type,row){
                var dato = $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 0, '$' );
                return dato.display(data) + "  <button type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditar' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></button>"
            }
```